# Snowmanning in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, layout

I'm trying to snowman some BGA pads in eagle but not coming across any real way to do it. Theres the teardrop.ulp but for whatever reason it doesn't add any teardrops to my pads.

Is there an easier way?
[image]

**edit**
An example of "Snowmanning" compared to teardrops
[image]

Comment: I've never heard it called "snowmanning" before.

Comment: What you could try is using the split tool to make a small segment just before the pad, and then change the width of that pad to be slightly wider. But that is a somewhat manual process. I don't know of any existing ULP to do it.

Comment: The teardrops.ulp doesn't output a script? In any case it fails with the message "No teardrops generated with the current parameters" no mater what the parameter.
I'm really suprised that I cant find a ULP on Autodesks website to do this. I'd have expected someone to have tried this by now.

Comment: Never mind, I thought it generated a script - obviously the description in the description in the ULP code is wrong.

Comment: It seems from a quick test that the teardrops ULP doesn't work on SMD pads, only Vias and THT pads.

Comment: I've came up with a workaround that I'm testing right now. If I just draw a circle on layer 1 of width zero then I can get the right size of snowman and drop it on top of the pad

Comment: You may get DRC errors doing that because the copper circles can't be tied to a net.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Fails DRC but I think I can just approve these in lieu of a better solution built into eagle.

Comment: I'd try my other suggestion to of drawing a short trace out of the pad with a width half way between the pad size and the original trace size. That will prevent DRC errors as it is all part of the routing.

Answer (score 2):

The existing "teardrop" scripts don't work because they only process vias and pads, whereas your BGA "pads" are actually "SMDs", which EAGLE handles differently.

I've been playing with this recently, starting with the teardrop ulp, refactoring and having it draw a single fat short wire instead of the "diamond" shape that it used for teardrops.  It's not quite complete, (the 'undo' feature doesn't work, it doesn't handle non-round SMDs or elongated pads, and the documentation needs updated, but it might be worth a try if you're still interested...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I7en3EZz3zS1rtGdqCW5XH1y1pqpcChR/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Link requires user to download an unknown file, of unknown type or size. Download at your own risk!

Comment: Re-uploaded as snowmen-ulp.txt, so that it can be previewed.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I7en3EZz3zS1rtGdqCW5XH1y1pqpcChR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a script for this but I intend on writing one depending on how often I might have to do this.

For now a manual method would involve drawing a circle with width 0 (to create a solid pad) on your top layer with a radius a little bit smaller than your pad.
Copy and paste as needed across your design.

DRC will fail with Overlap errors with this method however

[image]